# How do I convert a Minecraft world into a Google SketchUp map?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How would I go about converting a Minecraft world into a Google SketchUp map? I know how to do it SketchUp to MC world but not MC world to SketchUp.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google Sketchup can import data in the [following formats](http://help.sketchup.com/en/article/36217):

> - SketchUp (.skp).
> - Google Earth terrain.
> - 3DS (.3ds).
> - DEM (.dem, .ddf)

I've done a bit of research and there are plenty of 3DS resources of Minecraft elements freely available, so creating a Minecraft landscape in Sketchup should be possible.

It looks like in order to import a Minecraft world into Sketchup you'll need to go via another program though. [j-mc-2-obj](https://code.google.com/p/j-mc-2-obj/) generates OBJ models from Minecraft worlds. These obj models can then be imported into another program like 3DS max, and then exported again as a .3ds file.

I can't verify this method, as I don't have the appropriate software to hand, but it looks like it should be possible.

Comment: To convert the file you could also use [Blender3D](http://www.blender.org/) which is free ;)

Comment: I used jmc2obj and Blender to export it to COLLADA (`.dae`) and it worked perfectly with SketchUp Make 2017. Just make sure to check the Optimize Model box in the first tool.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment i don't believe anyone has implemented a way of doing this.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @MBraedley "no" is an answer too.